# How to use jQuery each to successfully console.log a JSON array value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

With my below Javascript I'm defining a JSON array as a variable:

```
var json =     [
  {
        "pk": 981,
        "name": "Uruguay",
        "distributor": {
            "id": 28,
            "name": "Store 1",
            "email": "CustomService@example.com",
            "phone": "",
            "site": "",
            "ownership": 1,
            "shipping_cost": 1600,
            "fulfilled": false,
            "items": [
                213,
                215,
                217
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 982,
        "name": "US Minor Outlying Islands",
        "distributor": {
            "id": 31,
            "name": "International",
            "email": "CustomerService@example.com",
            "phone": "1231231234",
            "site": "http://www.example.com",
            "ownership": 1,
            "shipping_cost": 1600,
            "fulfilled": false,
            "items": [
                213,
                215,
                217
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 983,
        "name": "Uzbekistan",
        "distributor": {
            "id": 31,
            "name": "International",
            "email": "CustomerService@example.com",
            "phone": "1231231234",
            "site": "http://www.example.com",
            "ownership": 1,
            "shipping_cost": 1600,
            "fulfilled": false,
            "items": [
                213,
                215,
                217
            ]
        }
    }
  ];
```

Then I'm attempting to use jQuery's *each* function and a value reference on the ***pk*** field to log the ***name*** field value to console.

```
$.each(json.pk, function(i, v) {
    if (v.pk == 981) {
        console.log(v.name);
        return;
    }
});
```

I've tried numerous variations of this but I can't seem to ever trigger the conditional which would allow me to console log values. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no `json.pk`, because `json` is an array. `json[0].pk` and `json[1].pk` do exist though. So what you want to actually loop over is just `json`, and then inside the loop you want to access the `pk` property of the current item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this way

```
$.each(json, function(i, v) {
    if (v.pk == 980) {
        console.log(v.name);
        return;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `json` in `$each` instead of `json.pk`

```js
var json =     [
  {
        "pk": 981,
        "name": "Uruguay",
        "distributor": {
            "id": 28,
            "name": "Store 1",
            "email": "CustomService@example.com",
            "phone": "",
            "site": "",
            "ownership": 1,
            "shipping_cost": 1600,
            "fulfilled": false,
            "items": [
                213,
                215,
                217
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 982,
        "name": "US Minor Outlying Islands",
        "distributor": {
            "id": 31,
            "name": "International",
            "email": "CustomerService@example.com",
            "phone": "1231231234",
            "site": "http://www.example.com",
            "ownership": 1,
            "shipping_cost": 1600,
            "fulfilled": false,
            "items": [
                213,
                215,
                217
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 983,
        "name": "Uzbekistan",
        "distributor": {
            "id": 31,
            "name": "International",
            "email": "CustomerService@example.com",
            "phone": "1231231234",
            "site": "http://www.example.com",
            "ownership": 1,
            "shipping_cost": 1600,
            "fulfilled": false,
            "items": [
                213,
                215,
                217
            ]
        }
    }
  ];
  
  $.each(json, function(i, v) {
    if (v.pk == 981) {
        console.log(v.name);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One can easily navigate in `JSON` object provided that the `json` of is type Array.

```
$.each(json, function (key, value) {
    console.log((key + 1), value);
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/t22qo51L/1/)